# WTP - Overlay is not copied when the overlaid project is open

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-wtp

I have the following scenario:

- I have a WEB App - lets call it **MyWebApp**
- It is based on some overlay which is not owned by me - lets call it **template**
- I wanted to create a wrapping of this overlay in my own code-tree - lets call it **my-template**

When I base **MyWebApp** on **template** - WTP works fine and my `wtpwebapps` dir is created as expected.
When I base **MyWebApp** on **my-template** - WTP does not copy the overlay at all.

When I run `mvn install` - the war I get is identical in both cases. With the slight difference in the `META-INF/maven` directory - in my version I don't see the

One important note - when I add the dependency to **template** back to my project - but leave the overlay to come from **my-template** - it works fine - so it looks like the problem is in the `pom.xml` of **my-template**.

I'm using:

- Maven 2.2.1
- Eclipse - STS - 2.9.2
- wtp 1.5

The problem only occurs when the **my-template** project is opened - when I close it, everything works fine.

I can also see it change in the `.settings\org.eclipse.wst.common.component` configuration file from:

```
<dependent-module deploy-path="/" handle="module:/overlay/prj/my-template?unpackFolder=target/m2e-wtp/overlays&amp;includes=**/**&amp;excludes=META-INF/MANIFEST.MF">
    <dependency-type>consumes</dependency-type>
</dependent-module>
```

To:

```
<dependent-module deploy-path="/" handle="module:/overlay/var/M2_REPO/com/mygroup/my-template/1.0-SNAPSHOT/my-template-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war?unpackFolder=target/m2e-wtp/overlays&amp;includes=**/**&amp;excludes=META-INF/MANIFEST.MF">
   <dependency-type>consumes</dependency-type>
</dependent-module>
```

Below is the `pom.xml` of the **my-template** project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.mygroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>my-template</artifactId>
    <version>16.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>template.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>template</artifactId>
            <type>war</type>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <overlays>
                        <overlay>
                            <groupId>template.group</groupId>
                            <artifactId>template</artifactId>
                        </overlay>
                    </overlays>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My question - is there anything wrong with my configuration? Or is it there a configuration for **WTP** I can change?

Comment: Did you have a chance to solve this problem ? 
If so could share the solution here ? Thanks.

Comment: I honestly don't recall - there was something there related to the fact that I had an overlay based on another overlay - eventually the project got canceled so I didn't get the chance to finish it out.

Comment: Ok, no worries. I will investigate a bit more then.